# Compiler documentation on Docfx

Tags: c#, docfx

I have the compiler documentation generation activated in my Visual Studio 2022, I work on a background service project with c#, the problem is that my compiler generates the Xml of the comments correctly, but my Docfx does not read it, it only considers the worker.cs class and nothing more.

my docfx.json:

```
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": [
            "**.csproj"
          ],
          "src": "C:\\Users\\TestProyect"
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api",
      "disableGitFeatures": false,
      "disableDefaultFilter": false
    }
  ],
  "build": {
    "externalReference": [
      {
        "type": "Xml",
        "source": "C:\\Users\\TestProyect\\data.xml"
      }
    ],
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**.yml",
          "api/index.md"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**.md",
          "articles/**/toc.yml",
          "toc.yml",
          "*.md"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "images/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": [
      {
        "files": [
          "apidoc/**.md"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "obj/**",
          "_site/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "dest": "_site",
    "globalMetadataFiles": [],
    "fileMetadataFiles": [],
    "template": [
      "default"
    ],
    "postProcessors": [],
    "markdownEngineName": "markdig",
    "noLangKeyword": false,
    "keepFileLink": false,
    "cleanupCacheHistory": false,
    "disableGitFeatures": false
  }
}
```